# Define short Class name Method name can reduce memory usage or software package size?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

```
byte[] Bytes;
Test test1 = new Test();
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, test1);
    Bytes= stream.ToArray();
}
```

This code can return the class size(maybe not accuracy class size). 
If i have short Method name in the Test class. The MemoryStream byte count will less.
So i curious does short Class/Method name can reduce memory usage or software package size **in theory**?

Comment: We're in 2015 dude. Memory is dirt cheap now. You can better spend your time in implementing some other useful feature of optimizing something useful.

Comment: do you mean the size of executable or the number of bytes representing the state of object in stream after it was serialized?

Comment: i know i shouldn't think about this question, but i just curious in theory.

Comment: In theory, the longer your names the longer the metadata has to be. So, in a particular point in memory you'll have a fewer bytes if the names are longer. Don't worry about it though. You're better off with descriptive class names that take up more memory than having a class named `X`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no.

As the assembly contains meta data about the classes and methods, their names appear there. However, that only exist once in memory, the instance of the class doesn't replicate this information.

The size of each class instance is independent of the length of the class and member names. By using shorter names you would save a few bytes in total, so that is by no means any efficient way to same memory.

The `BinaryFormatter.Serialize` method will include meta data with the data in the class, so that does not give an accurate measurement of how much memory a class instance uses.